# Как скрыть подпункт меню WordPress по заданой логике?

Tags: wordpress

Всем доброго времени суток. Вопрос по кастомизации меню.

Суть в том что есть меню и конкретно пункт меню с подменю. Нужно прятать подпункт если там нет событий (тип записей). Вопрос - как встроить в дочернюю тему логику скрытия подпунктов меню при отсутствии материала в нем?

Вопрос не в написании логики проверки на наличие материала, а именно на встраивание логики проверки.

То есть, как прописать логику вывода подпунктов меню в зависимости от чего-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'delete_empty_terms_from_menu', 10, 2 );
function delete_empty_terms_from_menu( $items, $args ) {
    // Проверяем, что область меню primary, чтобы не обрабатывать лишние меню
    if ( $args->theme_location === 'primary' ) {
        foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
            // Проверяем, что пункт меню относится к термину и что у него нет постов, и удаляем таковые.
            if ( 'taxonomy' == $item->type && get_term( $item->object_id )->count === 0 ) {
                unset( $items[ $key ] );
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Это вариант без запросов к БД - то есть более правильный.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*  
 *  Hide empty categories from nav menus
 */
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'gowp_nav_remove_empty_terms', 10, 3 );
function gowp_nav_remove_empty_terms ( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $empty = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE count = 0" );
    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        if ( ( 'taxonomy' == $item->type ) && ( in_array( $item->object_id, $empty ) ) ) {
            unset( $items[$key] );
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Все готово. Этот код идеально подходит.